# .htacces block all other domain

Tags: .htaccess, security

I searched a lot of on the internet, but i didn't found any really good solution for my problem. I want to block to include files from my server from all domain or ip except my own. I really hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.your_domain_name\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.your_domain_name.com/not_allowed_here.htm [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Now I write in my domain name and I be radirected to the not_allowed_here.htm. So my website doesn't work with that. I only want to block includes from other servers.

Comment: Make sure the url in your address bar is the same as what you had in the condition.